# Haxe syntax; what does the following mean?

Tags: function, syntax, declaration, haxe

I have the following bit of syntax:

```
Void -> Void
//in context example
private var _onClickEvents : List < Void -> Void > ;
```

which seems to be accepted as a type definition, the same as `Bool` or `TextField`. I presume it has similar use to how Haskell defines function type signatures?

Comment: Can you please add its contest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static public function sayHello() : String { return "hi!"; }`

has type: `Void -> String`

The last element is the type the function returns; previous elements are the types of the arguments.

`static public function factory(generator : String -> String -> String, times : Int) : Int -> String;`

Consider this function which takes as arguments one function (with 2 arguments and that returns a string) and an integer value and returns a function.

Its type is: `(String -> String -> String) -> Int -> (Int -> String)`

If you are in doubt what the correct type is, you can always use the `type` command. It is only used at compile time and returns in the console the type of its argument:

`type(factory);`

Should print what I wrote above.